# Javascript modules - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to learn modules from a tutorial. In have a folder in visual studio code/VScode which has two files, script.js & external.js.

Script.js imports content from external.js and prints text to console. I get the below error when I run script.js from vs code, with node.js run configuration. Can someone please tell me why this happens and how to fix it ? In comparison, imports in Java are simple.

```
import {keyValue} from './external.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1070:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)
```

**external.js :**

```
export let keyValue = 1000;
```

**script.js :**

```
import {keyValue} from './external.js';
console.log(keyValue);
```

**UPDATES :**
Node version - v12.16.2, upgraded to v14.4.0.

Comment: your `external.js` file needs to be inside the `root/modules` folder

Comment: you need to tell node that you are using esm and not cjs. Either package.json: type: module or name your files with ext .mjs or use esm node -r esm script.js

Answer (score 5):

## What's the version of node.js?

#### If node.js is version 13 or above, you can do either:

- add `{ type: "module" }` to package.json.

```
{
  ...
  scripts: "...",
  type: "module"
}
```

- rename `.js` to `.mjs`

#### If it's under 13, rename `.js` to `.mjs`, and run with additional params `--experimental-modules`.

```
node --experimental-modules script.js
```

### Or

You can also fix the `import statement outside a module` issue

by not using the import **statement** and using the dynamic import **function** instead.

**script.js**

```
import("./external.js").then((module) => {
    console.log(module.keyValue);
});
```

This form also supports the `await` keyword.

```
 let module = await import('./external.js');
 console.log(module.keyValue)
```

Comment: I upgraded it to v14.4.0. My tutorial does not mention package.json, but i setup one with npm init now. I am trying to understand how to make external.js a module which script.js can use.

Comment: @MasterJoe2 To make external.js as a module, you need to export it. and in ur script.js, import it. you can start from here, https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports

Comment: or u can update your post, including all files and file structures.

Answer (score -1):

it's because you are using es6 modules instead of the default module system for node which is common js. you could either use babel to transpile it or to use the .mjs extension